# Remove Focuslistener from a combobox

Tags: vaadin

I want to remove a focuslistener from a combobox in vaadin 6.8.9
Here is my code of focuslistener

```
tbCmbProductName.get(ar).addListener(new FocusListener(){
     public void focus(FocusEvent event){
         //do something
     }
});
```

How can i do that, any help please...

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to your FocusListener and then call removeListener with the same parameter.

Something like this

```
    final FocusListener focusListener = new FocusListener(){
        public void focus(FocusEvent event){
            //do something
        }
    };
    // To add
    tbCmbProductName.get(ar).addListener(focusListener);

    // to remove
    tbCmbProductName.get(ar).removeListener(focusListener);
```

Comment: Does the tbCmbProductName.get(ar) return the same instance each time?